# Do water movement in the seashore represent waves?

Tags: waves

[image]

I have seen water moving front and going back in the seashore.Do they represent waves?Explain.

Comment: According to definition of waves,"a wave is a disturbance or oscillation that travels through space and matter, accompanied by a transfer of energy. Wave motion transfers energy from one point to another, often with no permanent displacement of the particles of the medium—that is, with little or no associated mass transport."But here we can see the mass transport,which actually mean motion of water moving front and back don't represent waves.I don't how much it is correct.

Comment: This represents a wave in the same sense that any other oscillation of matter is a wave. Why would you think it doesn't?  Do you think a swinging pendulum represents a wave?  How about a tuning fork?  Or air temperature throughout the year?

Comment: This appears to be a homework question and no real effort has been made to explain the misconceptions or difficulty understanding why it may or may not be a wave

Answer (score 2):

When the water is deep the water moves in a circle as the waves propagate. See this [Hyperphysics page](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/waves/watwav2.html) for details, or do a Google image search for something like "wave water motion" for lots of examples.

So if you focus on any particular bit of water you'll see it moving both horizontally and vertically as the wave passes. As the water becomes shallower the circle is distorted into an ellipse (this image is copied from [this site](http://www.earthsci.org/education/teacher/basicgeol/coastal/coastal.html)):

[image: Waves]

The flattening of the ellipse means the vertical motion is reduced but the horizontal motion is increased, and that is why you see the sea moving towards and away from the beach.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a link to Hyperphysics in that 2nd sentence? Only asking because I don't see one.

Comment: Explain how water movement in seashore represent waves.

Answer (score 0):

According to definition of waves

> A wave is a disturbance or oscillation that travels through space and matter, accompanied by a transfer of energy. Wave motion transfers energy from one point to another, often with **no permanent** displacement of the particles of the medium—that is, with little or no associated mass transport.[this statement has been extracted from the wiki encyclopedia-[wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave)]

Water moving front and back at the sea shore,do have energy.For example,if a leaf is fallen on the water at sea shore,water moves it front and back,indicating that,they have ability to do work or in other words,they transfer energy.

Water moves front and back,indicating that,there is no permanent displacement of mass(water).The displacement of water to the front is temporary,it comes back to the initial position by moving back.**Therefore,water movement in the sea shore represents waves.**